# support:CardView minimum SDK?

Tags: android, gradle, android-cardview

I'm trying to add CardView support into my app for devices lower than Android L by adding the line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
```

I've then added compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 'android-L'

Now, unless I am mistaken, I thought that this would have built on my Nexus 5 in 4.4.4, however I get the error

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Am I missing something or misunderstood this?  Full build.gradle below:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gh.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 'android-L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0+'
    compile files('libs/TalkClient.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While CardView and RecyclerView are both [new widgets being added to the support library](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html#widgets) (and therefore will be available on API 7+ devices), during the developer preview they are limited to Android L devices only.

Comment: Thanks.   That's a bit of a bugger, my app is a Wear supported and I can't have the emulators running as Google Play Services doesn't work on the emulators

Comment: Yep, if you want both Android L and Google Play Services right now, you'll want to invest in a Nexus 5 or Nexus 7.

Comment: I've got a Nexus 5, but it's my daily driver.  I've tried Android L on it but its not stable enough for the amount of time I need my phone :(

Comment: If this answered your question, please do accept the answer to remove it from the unanswered question list.