# App not working on a specific mobile device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, emulation

I have created an android application. I have generated a signed `apk` and my app is working very well on all devices except `OPPO A37`.

I don't know what is the main issue. I have also tried to debug the app with the developer option. But the device is not showing on my android studio

**Build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wrfent.wrfnanbookings"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

       }
       buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
  
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'
    implementation 'fr.bmartel:jspeedtest:1.32.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.10'
}
```

Comment: check api level of mobile os and android studio build.gradel.

Comment: how to check it on both ?

Comment: send me your build.gradel screenshot

Comment: @DhruvSakariya I have added in my question

Comment: minsdk:-16
target:-28

Comment: and how to check in mobile?

Comment: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.

Comment: `my app is working very well on all devices except` That tells us nothing! You should exactly tell what does not work. With code and error messages.

Comment: @blackapps there is no error or message that appears on mobile. As already mentioned that the mobile device is not shown on the android studio in developer mode as well

Comment: But what does not work? And how did you manage to install your app on it?

Comment: Google `OPPO A37` is `Android 5.1`, is a very old, and EOS.

Comment: @blackapps the app was shared over WhatsApp. and the `apk` is installed and I am able to login into the app. But when I click on the buttons, the app doesn't respond i.e. a when a button is taped, it opens a list and that list doesn't show no matter how many times I have taped the button and vice versa. 

Also I am unable to do usb debugging as the device never shows on my android studio while it does shows "`You are on developer mode`" on the device

Comment: Enable MultiDex in your app and try again

Comment: Possibly related: [Android vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true is stopping app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41407811/295004)

Comment: `OPPO A37` being `Android 5.1` is still `minSdkVersion 22` Above the minSDK listed.  @Moeez If the list portion of the code is failing, can you please post the: touch detection, button press, and list open/close methods?  Note: May be using appCompat, and Cardview versions too advanced.  minSDK is theoretically 14, yet other users have reported needing [cardview-v7:21.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586863/supportcardview-minimum-sdk) or [cardview-v7:+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235038/dependecies-for-cardview-and-recyclerview-in-sdk-version-28) for some older phones.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use the feedback feature library
understand and fix bugs when your apps have a crash
[see this](https://www.acra.ch/docs/Setup)